# Setting Variable equal to line where keywords are found

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble printing the link the correct keywords are found in the following code:

```
import urllib2
from random import randint
import time
from lxml import etree
from time import sleep

a = requests.get('http://properlbc.com/sitemap.xml')
#time.sleep(1)
scrape = BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'lxml')
linkz = scrape.find_all('loc')
for linke in linkz:
    if "products" in linke.text:
        sitemap = str(linke.text)
        break



while True:
 #   sleep(randint(4,6))
    keyword1 = "properlbc"
    keyword2 = "products"
    keyword3 = "bb1296"
    r = requests.get(sitemap)
 #   time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('loc')
    for link in links:
        while (keyword1 in link.text and keyword2 in link.text and keyword3 in link.text):
            continue
        print("LINK SCRAPED")
        print(str(link.text) + "link scraped")
        break
```

The code is successful in looping until the link with the keywords is found but it doesn't print the specific link with the keywords, it prints the initial "link.text" instead of "https://properlbc.com/collections/new-arrival/products/bb1296"

Comment: you use `while` and `continue` to skip link with keywords so it doesn't print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
for link in links:
    if keyword1 in link.text and keyword2 in link.text and keyword3 in link.text:
        print("LINK SCRAPED")
        print(str(link.text) + "link scraped")
```

Or even

```
for link in links:
    text = link.text
    if keyword1 in text and keyword2 in text and keyword3 in text:
        print("LINK SCRAPED")
        print(text, "link scraped")
```

---

EDIT: to leave loop when it finds link

```
keyword1 = "properlbc"
keyword2 = "products"
keyword3 = "bb1296"

found = False

while not found:
    #sleep(randint(4,6))
    r = requests.get(sitemap)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('loc')
    for link in links:
        text = link.text
        if keyword1 in text and keyword2 in text and keyword3 in text:
            print("LINK SCRAPED")
            print(text, "link scraped")
            found = True # to leave `while` loop
            break # to leave `for` loop
```

Comment: Yes but will this loop until the link is added to the site?

Comment: to check if link was added to side you have to read page again. Looping only links is useless.

Comment: to exit loop when it finds link you can use `found = False` and `while not found:` instead of `while True`. And later set `found = True` inside `if keyword1 ...`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for explaining the Loops, looping the links didn't work because I had only requested the page once... Thanks for going the extra mile and rewriting the script

Comment: Reviewing this script, wouldn't, this script get stuck in the `for` loop if the keywords aren't found and not send another request?